# Stop SQL query in python

Tags: python, sql

Is there a way to let the user stop the execution of a sql query in python if it takes some long time? I am thinking of using a progress bar with a cancel button, but I wonder if there is a way to stop it in a clean way instead of killing abruptly the associated thread? (I am using both pysqlite2 and MySQLdb packages)

Comment: I think you'd be better off addressing why the query is taking so long

Comment: @OMG_Ponies: Usually the queries doesn't take much time, but for instance, I have a query that is taking more than 100 sec that involves some sorting and grouping of around a million rows.

Answer (score 3):

the only solution i see is to get the process id:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

and kill it:

```
KILL <thread_id>;
```

i would execute those commands with mysqldb.

However, you should be carefull about the rollback. See for example:
[If I stop a long running query, does it rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161960/sql-server-query-question-if-i-stop-a-long-running-query-does-it-rollback)

hope it helps

Comment: Is this considered a "clean" way to terminate a query?